# Call to undefined function parse_url() . why

Tags: php, laravel, heroku-postgres

I using php(in laravel) and postgresql on heroku.

I know how to connect database on this site → https://mattstauffer.com/blog/laravel-on-heroku-using-a-postgresql-database/

I use this Method for connecting database in php like this.

```
<?php
require('good_function.php');
if(isset($_POST['post_id'])){
   $p_id = $_POST['post_id'];
   $u_id = $_POST['user_id'];
   $url = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL'));
   $dsn = sprintf('pgsql:host=%s;dbname=%s', $url['host'], substr($url['path'], 1));
```

but show error`Call to undefined function  parse_url()` when I open my web site.

undifined? why

my php version 7.4.5.

please give me advice sir.

Comment: What exactly is the error message, including the file location it references? A screenshot would be helpful (you can paste them directly into the [question editor](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61788616/edit))

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote $url = parse_url(getenv('DATABASE_URL')); and gocha!

I copied code so it's might have another Character code.

thanks.